# Does Poison Spell deal damage to own units in its radius?

Tags: clash-of-clans

As in question title, does Poison Spell deal damage to own (attacker's) units under its radius, or only to enemy units? 
The description says "Defending units" but I want to make sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The spell will only deal damage to enemy units.

From the clash of clans wiki:

> It does damage and slows down all **enemy** Troops, Heroes, and Skeletons
>   inside its area of effect, but does not deal damage to buildings.

Answer (score 1):

It only does damage to enemy units. By defending units, it means any troops in the defenders clan castle (it also affects enemy heroes). Thus, you can drop a poison spell on top of your troops and it won't effect them.

read more about it [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Poison_Spell)